# Why do these buttons flow over the menu

Tags: html, css, button, position

I am currently building a website, and somehow the two buttons on the header (contact and more information) keep flowing over the menu on mobile. Somehow it works on Firefox but not on other browsers.

Link website: http://lwl.lightworklounge.nl/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Style.css
Line: 792**

```
nav { position: fixed; top: 0; z-index: 99999; }
```

**Style.css
Line: 690**

```
#menuToggle input[type=checkbox] {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -45px;
    left: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

Comment: Style.css Line: 811 - nav { position: fixed; top: 0; z-index: 9999; }

Comment: This will not solve the issue but will fix the nav bar and new error will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Just put below code in your css.

```
li.button1,li.button2 {
z-index: -1;
}
```